# Lost Lines in Kernel Log

Tags: logging, linux-kernel

I use printk many times in my code. Perhaps 100000 times! and the time-interval between each call is really short. At the end, when I check kernel log (/var/log/kern.log in Ubuntu 12.04) I see many of the lines are lost. Is there any way to avoid this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you printing so much info so quickly?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the log buffer size (CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT).

Comment: Thanks! Number of lost lines decreased but still some are lost